# I can't go down a line VB

Tags: vb.net, minecraft

I have followed a tutorial, and made a Minecraft server pinger, but I want all the information on different lines, like this :

```
Server online!
The message of the day is ...
There are 0/2 players
```

My code

```
Imports Wrapped
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles    Button1.Click
    Label3.Text = PingServer(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)

End Sub
Private Function PingServer(ByVal IP As String, ByVal port As Integer)
    Dim MySocket As New TcpClient(IP, port)
    Dim Socket As New Wrapped.Wrapped(MySocket.GetStream)
    Socket.writeByte(254)
    Socket.writeByte(1)
    If Socket.readByte() = 255 Then
        Dim mystring As String = Socket.readString()
        Dim mysplit() As String = mystring.Split(ChrW(CByte(0)))
        Return "The server is online"
        Return Environment.NewLine & "The message of the day is " & mysplit(3)
        Return Environment.NewLine & "There are" & mysplit(4) & "/" & mysplit(5) & "players"
    Else


        Return "Something went wrong! Please try again."



    End If
    Return ""

End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The Return keyword will return execution to the caller. So the first time it gets to Return it will return what is next to it and nothing else. In your case you will get only `The server is online`.

What you need is a concatanated string. There are numerous ways of doing that, one of them is as follows.

```
    Return "The server is online" & _
    Environment.NewLine & "The message of the day is " & mysplit(3) & _
    Environment.NewLine & "There are" & mysplit(4) & "/" & mysplit(5) & "players"
```

Notice that you do not have to have them in different lines, but is better for reading the code.